# Passing a string to second view controller's UILabel when performing segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, viewcontroller

I'm trying to pass an annotation's title to the second view controller with the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` method like this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    //My second VC's UILabel outlet
    self.lblAnnotationTitle.text = view.annotation.title;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gymDetails" sender:self];

}
```

When the view controller shows up, the label is not updated yet. Why is that so?

Also, is this the right way to pass properties to another view controller? If not, what is a better way to do this?

Comment: you need to create a string variable to get data and pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement `prepareForSegue` and pass the value there

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"gymDetails"]) {
        GymDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.ivar = @"Your Text here";
    }
}
```

Then in your view did load you should do like

```
lblAnnotationTitle.text = ivar;
```

Comment: Does that mean that I will have to create a new UIViewController Class and define it in my storyboard?

Comment: @iamhx without a class how you will update your second view controller's UILabel. You need to create a UIViewController Class for your second controller.

Comment: You have written `self.lblAnnotationTitle.text = view.annotation.title;` in your first view controller, where you are saying that `lblAnnotationTitle` is an IBOutlet of second view controller. It is not possible to assign the `IBOutlet`'s content from a different view controller's `self`. You need to create an object of second view controller, then only you can update the `IBOutlet`'s contents. @InderKumarRathore have shown you the perfect way to achieve your goal. :)

Comment: @AntonyRaphel yes. I've went ahead to create a class for my second view controller. I imported the secondVC.h in my firstVC.m file and put my text into the ivar. But in the viewDidLoad my text is a null value.

Comment: @iPeter, I linked the label to an IBOutlet in the FirstVC.h. My second VC is also using the same class which felt like a dumb thing to do so I added a new class.

Comment: @iamhx check that you are passing `view.annotation.title` from 1st VC to 2nd VC. With debug mode check _annotation.title_ you are getting or not and pass it over 2nd VC.

Comment: @AntonyRaphel it's not. I declared a variable `CustomAnnotation *myAnnotation` in interface of FirstVC.m, and on `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`, I passed `view.annotation.title` to `myAnnotation.title`. In the secondVC.h interface, I declared an `NSString *myTitle` and on `viewDidLoad` I would pass the string to `self.lblTitle.text`. In the `prepareForSegue` I did `secondVC *vc = segue.destinationViewController` and passed `myAnnotation` to the secondVC's NSString.

Comment: @iamhx with `NSLog` check before passing to 2nd VC, when you are tapped.

Comment: @AntonyRaphel, it's null until I initialized it with `[[CustomAnnotation alloc]init]` however the label is empty in the secondVC.

Comment: @AntonyRaphel, it worked all of the sudden! Instead of declaring the global object `CustomAnnotation *myAnnotation`, i figured it would be better to use NSString instead since I just want the value of the string.

Comment: I'm glad you found it!

Answer (score 1):

The better way to do that is to do inside the `-prepareForSegue` method.
Inside that method by looking at the identifier you can grab the `destinationViewController` and update with you model.
Pay attention those aspects:

1. if your view controller is contained inside a container view controller the destination view controller is the container view controller, so you need to extract your view controller from it
2. Until the segue is finished your view controller view is not loaded, this means that the connections between the outlet are still at nil, so if you force the label to be updated with the text, nothing will happen. One way to do is pass the text as a "model" and update the label inside the `-viewDidLoad` method of the destination view controller.

Comment: Is storyboard considered a container view controller? Because my second VC is also in the same storyboard as my first VC.

Comment: Storyboard are simply a representation of your flow and UI, it's a sort of XML file, so no they are not a container view controller. For instance if you are presenting modally your view controller and it's contained a navigation controller, the navigation controller is the container returned from the destination view controller.

Comment: I see... Yes I do have a navigation controller. How can I point it to the view controller if this is the case?

Comment: Check navigation controller properties in the documentation, there is a stack of all your VC pushed and if I remember well there is also a topViewController property

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "xxx" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? XXX {
            destination.xx = xx
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Is it possible to change this in Obj-C? I haven't learnt swift yet..